# WCF-Ajax enabled Web service. Service is not defined when deployed

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf, json

I have an Ajax enabled web service within my website.

The service sits in a WebServices folder within the Root of the website, the folder also contains it's own Web.config (as the bindings for the Ajax web.config conflict the configs on another layer of my site).

I have added the web service to the scriptmanager in my master page and used JQuery to call the service within a page.

This is all working fine running locally in IIS 7 (Vista).

However when I publish the Website (locally to file system as we have to copy the files manually to our test environment) then copy the files to our test environment (running IIs 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2), the web service doesn't work and I get a Javascript error saying "Service is not defined".

If I browse to the service then I can view the wsdl with no problems however if I try and view service.svc/js (the same url the page is looking for) then I recieve a 404 not found error.

I've done a lot of Googling on the subject and while there are loads of suggested Web.config fixes, I have tried multiple combinations and so far nothing seems to be working.

The service it's self is very basic.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "MyService")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class MyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public JSONObject DoWork()
    {
     ...Do some logic
     return JSONObject;
    }
}
```

JSONObject is a class I created that just holds some properties to be sent to the page. As I said this is all working hosted in IIS locally.

**---EDIT**

Here's the Web.Config that sits in the same directory as the web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
     <webHttpBinding>
       <binding name="default" />
     </webHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="MyWebsite.WebServices.MyService"
           behaviorConfiguration="MyWebsite.WebServices.MyServiceBehavior" >
      <endpoint address=""  behaviorConfiguration="MyWebsite.WebServices.MyServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyWebsite.WebServices.MyService" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyWebsite.WebServices.MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MyWebsite.WebServices.MyServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
        <enableWebScript />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I also have the following section in my root web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Can you post your configuration in web.config?

Comment: What differences do you see between deployments? Is the folder with services valid virtual directory or application on the target server? Are you using the same version of .NET framework, etc.

Comment: The Webservice folder is just a folder inside the Root of the Website application. The versions of .NET are the same, the only major difference is that one is IIS 7 on Vista and one is IIS 7.5 on Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve managed to track down the issue.

It comes down to patching. The following article mentions an update to fix the issue in IIS 7.5 and Windows 7 but the patch is also applicable to Vista and Windows Server 2008.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2520479

There is a second option to fix the issue which involves reordering the Handlers in the IIS applicationHost.config file on the machine affected, I have tried this and it does in fact solve the issue.

The second option is described in the article above.